# How can I configure django settings for SMTP relay service

Tags: django, smtp

[using smtp relay google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en)
I have following settings.

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'service_account@organization.org'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'service.accout.password'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
SERVER_EMAIL='no-reply.application@organization.org'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='no-reply.application@organization.org'
```

Our intention is to use dummy no-reply addresses. i.e. (no-reply.application@organization.org) that don't really exist.
It almost worked with the current setup, but as the outgoing e-mails were missing the FROM address (or had a non @organization.org address set), the smtp-relay server was replying with not authorized. Is there a way to configure this in the settings.py files?

Comment: you have to make an email that was not in use with the name of no-replay@organization.

Comment: There are ways to set default email in other application so  DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL should have worked fine in django. Creating no-reply email is not ideal.